# MySQL "Connections" show too high number - show status

Tags: mysql, innodb

We have website that have a lot of access/day, many writes and reads on the database. We are running InnoDB and Laravel, using this command:

```
 show status like 'Conn%';
```

Shows that we have 199641163 connections, and this number keeps increasing forever, I just wanna know if this is normal!?

Comment: According to the [documentation about that variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Connections), apparently so. I figure that value may reset after a server restart, but I've not checked. (the docs does not specify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

show status like 'Conn%'; This does not show active connections,it means the total number throughout history.

to check active connection you can use

```
SHOW STATUS WHERE `variable_name` = 'Max_used_connections';
```

or

```
show status where `variable_name` = 'Threads_connected';
```

In order to check the maximum allowed connections,

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "max_connections";
```